# Dual Boot with windows 8.1 and 12.04.4 ubuntu. With 2 drives in UEFI mode

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

So I was able to install ubuntu in legacy mode on my second ssd. Now I have learned that I can't dual boot with out ubuntu in UEFI mode. I have a disc with ubuntu live on it. I go into the boot menu and try to boot from disc to do a reinstall. (No data on ubuntu side and yes secure is off) now when I try to boot from disc I get I think it is grub telling me that "No device is set" and proceeds to give me junk on my screen in the form of pixels everywhere.

Now I know about removing hard drives is the easiest but not so much for an Alienware m17xr4. I don't have a good environment for that. Nor am I confident in my A+ abilities.

I have scoured the Internet and nothing really helps. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You must boot installer in UEFI mode, or if installed to gpt partitioned drive and have the efi partition, you can use Boot-Repair to convert to UEFI.

You have to use Something Else or manual install. And then you have to manually create your own partitions, minimum is efi as FAT32 with boot flag, / (root) as ext4 and swap not format, but lots of discussion of swap on SSD, so if you have lots of RAM you may not need it or even use it. I usually like to have a little like 2GB.

And best to create an efi partition first on drive if UEFI or or bios_grub partition if BIOS. Drive does have to be gpt partitioned if you did not do that the first time.

I used gparted and selected gpt under device, advanced & select gpt over msdos(MBR) default partitioning....

I find it easier to create partitions with gparted, but you still have to format and select mounts in Something Else.

At the partitioning screen at the bottom is a combo box. It will default to drive that is sda which probably is wrong. You need to change that to the drive that is the one you are installing Ubuntu into.

Convert MBR drive to gpt and UEFI boot when Windows is UEFI on another drive.

[How can I change/convert a  Ubuntu MBR drive to a GPT, and make Ubuntu boot from EFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from)

[How to Install Ubuntu on separate hard drive in a dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot)

Comment: I would have to reinstall then? Now for the efi partition, which I don't have, how big does that have to be? Also, is there an easy way to wipe/uninstall ubuntu first then do a reinstall or is it easier to just go straight from the disc?

Comment: The efi partition can be anything from 100MB which is Windows default and possibly a bit small to 500MB which may be a bit large. Only if doing a lot of add-ins like rEFInd or others.  If not converted to gpt, you probably have to use gparted. You have to boot installer in UEFI mode and that will by default convert drive to gpt and you will have to create new partitions.

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/398760/a-partitioning-question/398787#398787