# Hard Drive Partition and Mount issue

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 seems everything is okay ( I believe ) but when I checked with the hard drive partition, it is not the way I want.

I have two hard drive 500GB and 1TB. During the installation I have selected 500GB to install Ubuntu. However when I am checking now it is showing 1TB is the **Master Boot Record**

Please refer the image below
[image]

Also it is not showing 1TB space but only partition space is 255MB. I have never created this partition, which is also strange to me.

Please refer the image how I am getting on my explorer

[image]

- 255 MB Volume
- UII (ignore it is my USB)
- Computer ( I think this is 500GB drive but only 492GB available ??? )

Can anyone please guide me how to resolve the issue where I can have full space of 1TB hard drive so I can save all my work date there and use 500GB for development.

Thanks a lot...!

Comment: Ah! deleting partition was as simple as just a click. Just select the particle (orange patch) than clicking on the `-` button done that. Now just formatted entire 1TB hard drive but Do not have any idea how to Mount it to use

Comment: Just deleting partitions without being sure what is in them can be dangerous. If you used any of the default install options, grub2's boot loader would be installed to the MBR of the drive seen as sda. Only Something Else gives you the option on where to install the boot loader. You do need to partition either MBR or gpt the drive and then create and format partitions that you may want. Larger drive: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme two drives one is SSD: http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: I appreciate your help. However I am layman in Ubuntu so many words are new to me. Such as SSD, MBR etc. Can you please explain me little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement "1TB is *the* Master Boot Record" is not exactly the right way of looking at things. The dialog is indicating the [partitioning method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table), not the location of the [boot sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector) for your installation.  There is an unfortunate ambiguity between these two meanings of [master boot record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record).

However, if this was in fact where your boot sector resides then deleting this partition may have killed your boot -- and re-installation might be your best bet.  Installing to a multiple disk system is a bit of an advanced operation and may require some deeper understanding to fully manage the process.  One way of simplifying this would be to physically remove the extra disk while you perform the installation.

As an aside: Your safest bet, given the starting point of this question, might have been to simply ignore the 255 MB partition and just add a new partition (using the "Disks" utility that you showed) in the remaining space on that device.  Wasting 255 MB of a 1TB disks is not a significant loss.

To mount the drive manually, you should be able to do that using the file manager (what you called "explorer") -- just click on the item in the "Devices" list.  To have it mounted automatically, you should be able to manage that through the "Disks" utility -- look for "Edit Mount Options...".

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I have problem in mounting the 1TB drive. It is not showing in File Manager > Devices list. Any idea or suggestion please!

Comment: Ah! actually when I have formatted it, I realized didn't set Ext4 and just re-formatted by setting it Ext4 and now all is well. Thanks a lot..!