# Best partition scheme on 128GB SSD and 200GB HDD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

first here are my PC specs: 2x128GB SSD 1x 1TB HDD and 16GB RAM
I have already installed Windows 7 on one of my SSD's.

I did a partition on the 1TB HDD with Windows disk management. So Windows got 800GB of space and Ubuntu will use 200GB, when it is installed.

Now I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my other SSD. My question is, what is the best partition scheme?

/ will obviously go on the SSD, but what about /home - HDD or SSD? My thought was, that / and /home go on the SSD, because with 128GB I have plenty of space. And /media or /mnt will go on the HDD. Is that good?

I also make a 8GB swap partition on the HDD (0.5 * 16GB RAM = 8GB).

And if I would want to do an upgrade when Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is released in two months, do I have to do a clean install? (Is 16.04 LTS worth it, when I have already 14.04 LTS on my PC?)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? My current gpt partitioned 128GB SSD already has both 14.04 & 16.04 installed. I probably will reinstall 16.04 as with all the updates it gets lots of logs and history that needs housecleaning. I used 25GB for both / (root) partitions including /home, but all data is in /mnt/data on HDD.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: I think BIOS. I have the Asrock B85M-HDS.
So I set /mnt/data as mount point for the HDD in the Installing partition menu?

Comment: You cannot set a /mnt/data during install, but have to manually add it after the install. This uses /media/storage: http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage And: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198