# Multi HDD/SSD Partitioning Scheme - where the partitions live?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

In the [article](https://wiki.debian.org/Multi%20HDD/SSD%20Partition%20Scheme) it is not clear where the partitions "live" ?
There are 6 partitions: from `boot-fs (md0)` to `bulk-data-fs (md6)`.
It looks like all the partitions are on the HDD ??
Shouldn't some of the partitions be on the SSD (like `/`) and other on the HDD (like `/swap`, `/home` and `/work-data`) ?

Comment: The article you linked  is for raid disks under Linux and requires extensive knowledge of mdadm and mdraid... It's not for the faint of heart and a little off topic for AskUbuntu I believe. None-the-less here is some more detailed information on raid setup: [mdraid overview](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Software_RAID)

Comment: The article that you refer to is extremely terse, and if you're not using RAID, it'll be easy to get confused. In answer to your question... **IN GENERAL**, in a 2 disk environment, one small SSD and one large HDD, you put root (/) on the SSD, and /home, /swap on the HDD. Of course, if the SSD is large enough, put everything but /swap on the SSD. If you need more clarification, please be more specific about what you actually want to do IN YOUR ENVIRONMENT. Cheers, Al

Comment: See these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Answer (score 0):

- `/boot`          (md0) is on **SSD** and **iHDD** and **eHDD** (via RAID 1)
- `/`              (md1) is on **SSD** and **iHDD** and **eHDD** (via RAID 1)
- `/var`           (md2) is on **iHDD** and **eHDD**         (via RAID 1)
- `/swap`          (md3) is on **iHDD** and **eHDD**         (via RAID 1)
- `/home`          (md4) is on **SSD** and **iHDD** and **eHDD** (via RAID 1)
- `/mnt/work-data` (md5) is on **SSD** and **iHDD** and **eHDD** (via RAID 1)
- `/mnt/bulk-data` (md6) is on **iHDD** and **eHDD**         (via RAID 1)

So:

1. internal SSD as **SSD** = `/boot` (md0) + `/` (md1) + `/home` (md4) + `/mnt/work-data` (md5)
2. internal HDD as **iHDD** = `/var` (md2) + `/swap` (md3) + `/mnt/bulk-data` (md6) + RAID 1 of [`/boot`, `/`, `/home`] (md10) + RAID 1 of [`/mnt/work-data`] (md50)
3. external HDD as **eHDD** = RAID 1 of [`/var`, `/swap`, `/mnt/bulk-data`]  + RAID 1 of [`/boot`, `/`, `/home`] + RAID 1 of [`/mnt/work-data`]

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to expand your answer. Expected outcome and such like.