# Live Boot USB Install of 16.04 fails on HP Pavilion 23

Tags: system-installation, hp, usb-installation, startup-disk-creator

I have an old HP Pavilion and I created a live boot USB of the Ubuntu 16.04.1 desktop image using `Startup Disk Creator`.  The install works fine (I'm installing over windows - completely nuked it), except for that it does not ask me to remove the USB drive after clicking restart.  This results in the machine booting right into the live usb menu.  I just remove the USB drive at this point and try booting the machine fresh.  It fails with the message `No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed`.

Tried the install multiple times and it has the same result each time.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: http://paste2.org/J4PF9GeC

Comment: Run Boot-Repair's advanced mode and check "use standard efi file" That will copy shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.  Your UEFI may auto add an entry to boot UEFI hard drive or fallback. If not  you can add one. And since only booting Ubuntu you can add a boot of shimx64.efi but using Windows description. Details in I 1 and IV:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: http://paste2.org/mJcfB0aB

Comment: Attempting to switch over to an SSD, so just keeping the pastebin here for notes: http://paste2.org/c5OIb2L0

Comment: You may get issues updating or reinstalling grub on the sdc drive. In UEFI mode grub only installs to ESP - efi system partition on sda. Best to partition new drive in advance & install with Something Else. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installationand: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  It's working now, but if I run into issues during an update I'll read up more.  I'm using a 128 GB Sandisk Micro USB.  Is there a standardized approach I can use for this scenario.  My goal is to have all OS and application files as well as my user account data load from the SSD.  I'll only use the internal drive for backup.

Comment: Some suggestions, but every user has his own requirements: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I was looking for - Thanks!!!