# Dualboot Windows & Ubuntu in SSD+HDD drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd, windows-10

I have an ASUS laptop that has a 128 GB SSD + a 1 TB HDD. I'd like to install Ubuntu on the SSD but use the HDD to store data. I would like to keep using Windows (installed on the SSD and data stored on the HDD) and be able to have a dual boot when I start my computer.

Is it possible to do this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: See these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't hard at all. All I did was follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) specifically on the "*If you have disk that contains Windows installed*" answer.

The only different thing I did different from the guide was that I made the **swap** and **root `/`** partitions in my SSD drive and the **`/home`** partition in my HDD drive.

Everything works smoothly now.