# Dual boot Win 10 + Ubuntu SSD+HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

first of all thank you for answering.

I have a 120GB SSD and a 1TB HDD and I want to dual boot with Windows 10. I tried with this configuration:

SSD

/ (ext4 20GB)
/usr (ext4 15GB)
/boot/efi (ext4 250MB)

HDD

/var (ext4 3GB)
/tmp (ext4 8GB)
/home (ext4 50GB)
swap (none 24GB) (RAM 16GB)

I don't know if I am doing OK, as I tried to install it but installation gets stuck at "Saving installed packages..." and it doesn't continue. I wonder if it could be cause I didn't  partitioned as I had to. I don't find any post where this happens so I ask here.

Thanks!

Comment: Your partitioning scheme is too complicated and there's not enough space in /  .  At least 25GB is recommended for / and you'll probably need more than that. We can discuss the exact amount of / that is required. All you need is / and swap and optionally /home. With an SSD you don't need to allocate that much swap space, in fact just accept the default swap space which is allocated by the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: The efi system partition (ESP) must be FAT32. Since Windows also has ESP, it will be shared, do not create another.  Ubuntu with 17.04 and later uses a swap file, not a swap partition, but a swap partition will be used if found. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & other SSD/HHD:http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: My main worry is the SSD. As it has limited read and write cycles I don't want to reduce them unnecessarily. So I read that partitioning hard drives as explained above it would be better for the SSD. Which is the exact partition scheme you propose?

Comment: The more information that you provide, the more specific the recommendation can be. Let's start with a general recommendation. SSDs are rugged and durable so read and write cycles is not the most important issue. Disk space on an SSD is expensive compared to disk space on an HDD so it's important to conserve valuable space on the SSD by not cluttering it with unnecessary partitions.

Comment: I finally installed everything in the SSD with 40GB for Ubuntu. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the `/` partitioning on the SSD instead of on the HDD will give much better performance and stability, but your partitioning scheme is too complicated and there's not enough space in `/` . At least 25GB is recommended for `/` and you'll probably need more than that. We can discuss the exact amount of `/` that is required. All you need is / and optionally swap and `/home`, but in new installations of Ubuntu 17.04 and later a swap file is created instead of a swap partition, so you don't need a swap partition either.

The more information that you provide, the more specific the recommendation can be. Let's start with a general recommendation. SSDs are rugged and durable so read and write cycles is not the most important issue. Disk space on an SSD is expensive compared to disk space on an HDD so it's important to conserve valuable space on the SSD by not cluttering it with unnecessary partitions.