# SSD (Windows/Linux) and HDD (shared storage/reserved storage for Linux)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my SSD, but I also want to partition the HDD so that:

1. There is a 1To shared space between the OS(s)
2. The rest is reserved/allocated to Linux (Windows can't access it)

How should I proceed?

PS: I am new at this and I can't seem to find an easy-to-understand explanation on how storage restriction works.

Comment: Your tag says 14.04, if newer system 16.04 may be better. Some more info: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & old but still valid: https://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme & https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Restriction is unnecessary as Windows can not natively read Linux partitions, while Linux can read windows partitions. Thus to share between them, format the partition with NTFS. For a partition that is Linux only format it ext4.