# How to install Ubuntu with SSD and HDD

Tags: software-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I want to install Linux on my main PC but it has an SSD and a 1TB HDD, i want to know how to use the SSD only for the OS and some programs and the HDD for everything else (i use it this way on Windows 10), is this possible? If it is can someone tell me how to install it that way? Thank you

Comment: See these: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

- create unallocated space on the SSD, 20GB is more than enough.
- create unallocated space on the HDD, as much as you feel is needed.
- Create a partition on the SSD as ext4 on the unallocated space and name the mountpoint `/`.
- Create a partition on the HDD as ext4 with a mount point you create yourself.
- after install open a terminal and set the mountpoint to your user.
- after install open a termimal and remove all the visible directories in /home/$USER/ (so not the hidden files).
- edit `~./config/users-dirs.dirs` and change it to your mountpoint.
- put a copy of `users-dirs.dirs` on your HDD.

This way you keep all system related files and settings on the SSD and all personal data on the HDD.

When you re-install: format / and mount the mountpoint without formatting. Remove dirs in /home/$USER/ and copy `users-dirs.dirs`  on the HDD to `~./config/`

Comment: +1 though depending on how many applications you have installed 20GB is not always more than enough. On my desktop where I have a similar setup / consumes about >30GB

Comment: I have a server with a 10Gb / with apache and a 500Gb+ mysql database: basically user data is stored elsewhere. Just with software that you actually use you will never hardly reach 20Gb.