# Recommended partitioning for an Ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, 18.04, ssd

I have a SSD 256 GB and a HDD 1000 GB mounted.

I suppose it would be best to use the SSD for standard software and the HDD for user data. Is this the preferred usage? If 256 GB is not sufficient, can I put some of the software on HDD?

How should I partition the disk space for installing Ubuntu? 
(no dual boot for Windows or other OS) I'm using gparted.

What kind of formatting should I use?

I'd appreciate a detailed answer as I am new to this.

Comment: [This](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver) may help.

Comment: Now you only need an ESP - efi system partition and / (root). Most desktop installs do not need /boot, and now swap is a file, not a partition. Otherwise these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation  My own full install uses about 7.5GB of my 25GB / (root) partition, but all data is on HDD. I have multiple installs of Ubuntu for tests since I have room, but do not fully allocate new drive.

Comment: I think daily usage scenario is important.  Actually 256GB is quite enough for average user and does not require special care.  For me I'll just install Linux on SSD using whole disk, and just mount 1TB HDD under /mnt, and you can link folders to it from your Home anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I can only show you [how I partitioned my disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irtd0.jpg) for Ubuntu 18.04 Mate on my old 2010 netbook with a memory of 1gB.

Swap is big because of my small memory