# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on a machine with SSD + HDD?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

What will be the default behavior in terms of partitioning when installing Ubuntu 18.04 on a machine with 220 GB SSD + 1TB HDD?

Are there any reasons why I should modify the default behavior and go for manual partitioning?

For info, I am not going for dual boot, Ubuntu will be the only OS.

Comment: Stick to a single question, though I think both questions are already well answered in the Ubuntu installation docs: the installer will make best recommendations for installation targets and partition layout but you can always choose drives and partition manually. Whether to do so depends _entirely_ on your specific needs, which is not part of your question.

Comment: IMHO there is no reason to do anything manually on installation stage if there is no special reason for that. I have the same configuration and I am using btrfs fs and an ext4 partition on HDD for Dropbox, but that's a special case.

Comment: Default install is just / (root). If UEFI then it will also want an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) on first drive usually sda, but some have newer NVMe SSDs. What brand/model system, some need boot parameters. What video card/chip? Nvidia needs boot parameter. Most need UEFI updates & SSD firmware updates.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Swap now not required as it uses a swap file. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Older: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme