# 2 OS's on 2 different drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

First of all hello to everyone , I'm new here and this is my first question.(I've seen that someone else has asked something similar but bear with me) 
 250 nvme ssd just for windows 
 800Gb for media and stuff 
 200Gb for ubuntu
 i booted up a flash drive and went on with it , installed ubuntu on the 200gb partition and then i tried booting into it using the mobo's boot menu but it was nowhere to be found. What did i do wrong and what should i do to make it work ? All help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What brand/model system? Did you install in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS that Windows is installed? If Windows pre-installed it must be UEFI as Microsoft has required that since 2012 on new systems. But installers will boot and then install in BIOS mode which you normally do not want. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: i somehow did it , i think my mistake was in the device selection process (i noobed out). I have another question though , is there a way that i could maybe make Ubuntu boot from the SSD but everything else (apps, files, etc.) gets stored in the HDD ?

Comment: If you have 25GB on SSD, you have have all of / (root) on SSD and then install with /home on HDD. Older instructions have a swap partition, but Ubuntu now uses a swap file, so no swap partition is required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu You also do not need /boot unless you have so little space on SSD that is all you can have on it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: Hey , thanks man that's what i had in mind. I didn't know that the swap partition was not necessary so i made one from the get-go. Is it possible to do what you said from inside Ubuntu ? (Also another question , my time settings particularly in win10 are getting messed up whenever i switch , any ideas?)
      
           Thanks again this time in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've installed Ubuntu to a physically different hard disk than Windows, you will need to tell the BIOS itself to boot from the different HDD. It should be something like Escape or the `F9` or `F12` keys to enter the one-time boot menu.
*You don't want to change the boot order unless you specifically want to boot Linux by default. We're looking to get into the One-Time Boot Menu, which allows you to pick the current boot drive but not change the default away from Windows.* Bear this in mind. If you enter BIOS setup, try another key. Some machines show different options. For example, most ASUS machines I've used you simply press Escape and decide a boot device (or Enter Setup at the bottom). Most Dell machines use F12 for the one time boot menu, and most HP machines use F9 for this. There may be instructions onscreen, look for those on the boot screen splash (unless it's a newer machine that immediately goes into Windows).

When in the boot menu, you should see a hard disk drive on top, that's going to be the higher priority one. Since you boot into Windows each time from what I understand, your PC has given that drive a higher priority. Thus, we can deduct that your first HDD entry won't be it. Since you mentioned it's an SSD, if the boot says anything about an SSD and the Ubuntu disk isn't one, don't select it. Look for a hard drive option that's lower than another hard drive one. Don't try USB or ODD boots, as those are for USB installers and DVD installers, respectively.

Comment: Hey man , thanks for all the info <3. I've already done all that and now successfully dual-boot from different drives , but i was wondering if there is a way to configure the now existing Ubuntu installation to boot from the SSD and everything else (apps, files, etc.) to get stored in the HDD

Comment: I'm really glad I could help! If you want, you can probably configure GRUB to look for Windows installs on other hard drives and set this HDD as the primary HDD in your BIOS, so that it boots from this drive's boot partition, asks you if you want Windows or Ubuntu, and then if you choose to use Windows, the GRUB menu will just hand off control to the SSD like normal. Might just see a bit of funny "Windows spinny wheel on the grub menu" type stuff while Windows loads this way, as I've experienced, but overall it would probably work OK.

Comment: This is a good article you can take a look at, from Unix & Linux, which should help you with a similar issue.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120232/dual-boot-windows-on-second-harddrive-uefi-gpt-system

If my answer helped completely solve the question mentioned above, please kindly press the "check mark" next to my answer to mark it as correct. It helps my reputation and directs others reading this to that answer first, in case they have a similar issue. Have a great day!

Comment: First of all thanks again , this time fore the additional info and secondly , after i carefully selected my device i didn't even have to change the boot order GRUB did everything by its self and everything is properly detected.

Comment: Very well, looks like problem solved! I'm assuming GRUB shows a menu on startup, with Windows and Ubuntu shown?

Comment: Yes , yes everything is peachy except the time settings in win10 which get messed up every time i switch.

Comment: On time issue: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts