# Partitions for Dual Boot Win10 + Ubuntu with OS in SSD and HDD as storage

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

My curent notebook has 120GB of SSD and 1TB of HDD, with Windows 10 installed in the SSD and using HDD as storage. I thought about making a dual boot with Ubuntu 18 OS in the SSD and storing files and programs in the HDD (like in Windows).

1 - Is this a pratical/good idea? I will need to work with several files and programs in both systems (and perhaps a game or two in Windows), so I'm beliving this to be the best setup. As I prefer Ubuntu for daily activities, it may be nice to use some SSD for it. 20GB would be enough?

2 - Should I then make a SSD partition for `/` and other HDD partition for `/home` (and `/var` or `/usr`)? I would like programs on Ubuntu (Gimp, LibreOffice, Spyder, Firefox, VLC) to be stored in the HDD given my limitated SSD.

3 - I have 16GB of RAM and would like to have probably a 16GB swap for hibernation and support. Any problem using HDD for swap (given the limitations) while `/` is in SSD?

4 - Is there a good walkthrough for partitioning these things in Windows and then installing Ubuntu like so?

Comment: Depends on how much Windows has used. NTFS needs 30% free to work well. But Ubuntu can install in a 25GB / (root) partition and if /home is on HDD that is all you need. Ubuntu now uses swap file. Hibernation typically not recommended. Suspend does not use swap.  Older /boot & swap not now required.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme &
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk &

Comment: Windows is already using 56GB, so I would have to let 80GB to have 30% free, right? Not counting updates. I could than use about 40GB for Ubuntu. Thanks for the references, the last one is particulary interesting. I would like to be able to acess files from both OSs, but I may be still a bit unsecure to do so.

Comment: If you have lots of space on HDD, then add both /home or ext4 data partition for Linux only data, and a NTFS data partition for any data you may want to shared between Windows & Ubuntu. I did that back when I had XP. But now with Windows 10 you have to have fast start up off & Windows may turn it back on. If not off, you will not be able to see any NTFS partition nor boot Windows from grub, only from UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions