# Manual partition issues

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Xubuntu through Unetbootin, but instead of asking me whether I want to automatically install the OS or manually partition it, it instantly goes to manual partition. Can I get some tips on how I can partition the system? (My drive is 64 GB.)
Thanks!

Comment: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation
Older /boot & swap not now required.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme &
http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd &

Comment: What version of Xubuntu are you installing, 20.04 or 20.10?

Answer (score 0):

### Install Xubuntu through UNetbootin

I have just installed Xubuntu 20.04 using a Live USB drive made with Unetbootin-700.

I used the **Installation Type Option** `Erase disk and install Xubuntu` and the
installation went as planned.

**Manual partitioning was not required.**

- From Unetbootin menu select `Install Xubuntu`, (if 20.10 select `Default`, then `Install Xubuntu`).
- From the installation menu select: Language, Keyboard, Network and Updates preferences.
- From the Installation type Screen select `Erase disk and install Xubuntu`.

[image]

If you want LVM and Encryption or an Experimental ZFS, the select `Advanced features`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Manual partitioning can seem intimidating but it actually is not, u primarily need 3 partitions

- `/root` - this stores everything related to OS
- `/swap` - this is more like the page file in windows
- `/uefi` - The third thing is whether u will need a UEFI partition
  but I believe that depends on how recent us PC / laptop build is
  and whether it has UEFI

Below is a good link that might help u

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGRQsONv0vA

Do let us know if u found success in this endeavour :)

Comment: Almost all is wrong. There is no `/uefi` and `/root` is not for "everything related to OS"